# gcc archives not considered when linking?

Tags: gcc, linker, unix-ar

Should it make a difference whether a gcc linker links archive files or object files (or both)?

Background: 
In an embedded project, an ISR (which is of course not referenced by any other source code) is located as the only function in a file. This file is compiled to an object file and then put into an archive file.
Other functions in other files are compiled to separate object files.
The binary is built without complaints and runs on the target with no exceptions, no matter whether the linker uses the ISR object file or the ISR archive file.
However, if using the archive file, the ISR is *not* linked. 
Plus, if there is any other reference (e.g. a variable used by some other function in some other file) in the same file, it *is* linked completely.
Why this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it makes a difference.

Any object file that is specified on the linker commandline is linked
into the executable, regardless of whether any of the symbols that it
defines are referenced by the executable.

The linkage of a static library is different. It is an archive of object
files. For each object file in the archive, the linker will determine
whether that object file provides a definition for any of the symbols
that are so far undefined at that point in the linkage. If it does so,
then the linker will extract that object file from the archive and
link it in the executable; otherwise not.

This behaviour is as documented for the [ld, the GNU linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) `{- l | --library }`
option:

```
-l namespec
--library=namespec
    ...
    The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where 
    it is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol 
    which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive 
    on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s) 
    from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing 
    later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the 
    archive again.
    ...
```

(To see that this applies to linkages invoked with `gcc` or another GNU compiler,you may need to know that the named compiler is simply a tool-driver that delegates to the appropriate tool for discharging the commandline options that are presented: when it sees options that call for a linkage, it calls `ld`.)

Hence the object file containing the unreferenced ISR is not linked when 
it is in a library, and contains no other referenced symbols, and it *is*
linked when it is not in a library, or when it contains some other
referenced symbol.

Comment: Good explanation! So we can say it's not a bug, it's just a fact one has to know? I spent almost a whole day on this issue, and found nothing relevant. Am I too dumb to get this from some "official" documentation or isn't there just any?

Comment: Updated to cite documentation.